# C# How to place a comma after each word but the last in the list

Tags: c#

I totally new to C# and learning as I go.  I am stuck on issue which I'm hoping an experienced programmer can help.  I have added a CheckedListBox to my form and added a collection of 6 items to it.  I need all but the last item selected to have a comma placed beside it, so my question is: how can I tell C# NOT to place a comma beside the last item selected?

```
foreach (object itemChecked in RolesCheckedListBox.CheckedItems)
{
    sw.Write(itemChecked.ToString() + ",");
}
```

Thanks for any help received!
Dan

Comment: I would recommend using string instead of the foreach loop as in my solution.

Comment: See better answer in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771741/how-to-remove-last-comma-from-query-c-sharp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A way to enhance your example could be:

```
var index = 0;
foreach (object itemChecked in RolesCheckedListBox.CheckedItems)
{
    if ( index>0 ) sw.Write( "," );
    sw.Write(itemChecked.ToString());
    index++;
}
```

Not elegant, but working.

Answer (score 53):

It can be done using [string.Join()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx) method:

```
string commaSeparated = string.Join(",", 
                RolesCheckedListBox.CheckedItems.Select(item => item.ToString());
```

For example:

```
string[] names = new []{ "a", "b"};
string separatedNames = string.Join(",", names);
```

Will result that *`separatedNames`* will be *`"a,b"`*

Comment: `Select` is only defined for `IEnumerable<T>` so you need to put `Cast<object>()` after CheckedItems since it only implements `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @Lee, good point, RolesCheckedListBox.CheckedItems.Cast<object>().Select(item => item.ToString()) may be required

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx) function instead of looping:

```
sw.Write(string.Join(",", RolesCheckedListBox.CheckedItems));
```

Answer (score 4):

In 4.0 you can simply use [string.Join(string separator, IEnumerable values)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx) that calls the ToString() method for all non-null values:

```
var commaSeparated = string.Join(",", RolesCheckedListBox.CheckedItems);
```

Answer (score 2):

In .Net 4 you can use static [`String.Join<T> Method (String, IEnumerable<T>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx) and print concatenated string.

Otherwise the easy way is to prepend comma to all elements but the first one:

```
bool shouldPrependComma = false;
foreach (object itemChecked in RolesCheckedListBox.CheckedItems) 
{
  if (shouldPrependComma) sw.Write(",");
  sw.Write(itemChecked.ToString());
  shouldPrependComma = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. transform your ListItemCollection to a string array using linq
2. use String.Join

Like:

```
public string ItemsToString(ListItemCollection items)
{
    string[] stringArray = (from ListItem item in items where item.Selected select item.ToString()).ToArray();
    return String.Join(", ", stringArray);
}
```

you could use it by

```
sw.Write(ItemsToString(RolesCheckedListBox.CheckedItems));
```

Or if you prefer a single line for the job:

```
sw.Write(String.Join(", ", (from ListItem item in RolesCheckedListBox.CheckedItems select item.ToString()).ToArray()));
```

Comment: Very nice! Solve the leading comma problem in two lines of code!

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (object itemChecked in RolesCheckedListBox.Items)
            {
                if (itemChecked != RolesCheckedListBox.Items[RolesCheckedListBox.Items.Count - 1])
                    sw.Write(itemChecked.ToString() + ",");
            }
```

That should help you. Also, I just used "Items", you used CheckedItems. Change all instances of Items to CheckedItems if you want to only iterate through checked items.

Comment: Thank you all for your quick responses this has worked a treat!!

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was this.  You have to be careful with the values you're working with as they may be empty or have whitespace, etc., in my case I made I sure .Trim():

```
string[] itemsToListSeparatedByComma = { item1, item2, item3, item4 };
List<string> itemsToListSeparatedByCommaList = new List<string>();

foreach (var item in itemsToListSeparatedByComma)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Trim())) continue;
    itemsToListSeparatedByCommaList.Add(item);
}

string finalString = string.Join(", ", itemsToListSeparatedByCommaList);
```

Answer (score -1):

Jon Skeet implemented [SmartEnumerable](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/miscutil/) for this kind of problem.