# how to remove last comma from query C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am doing something as follows..

```
querybuilder = ("SELECT Type, Text FROM [Element] WHERE Id IN( ");
foreach (var item in CaseIdList)
{
   querybuilder += item + ",";
}
querybuilder += ")";
```

at the last insdie the closing bracket  I am getting a comma. How to remove that.

Comment: @Serge, maybe hes using an older version of .NET?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

use `TrimEnd(',');` to remove last comma from the string, [`string.TrimEnd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx)

After the foreach loop use:

```
querbuilder = querybuilder.TrimEnd(',');
```

Instead of concatenating string, you may use [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) class.

Comment: Or you can simply do: `querybuilder = querybuilder + (String.Join(",", CaseIdList)) + ")";`

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, I'd try to avoid including the values themselves directly. Use parameters where possible - it's less simple for `IN(x, y, z)` style parameters, but you can either use a *table-valued parameter* or simply dynamically create the parameter list (e.g. to `IN(@p0, @p1, @p2)`)

Secondly, I'd avoid using string concatenation in a loop - use `StringBuilder` if you really have to loop round.

Thirdly, I'd use `string.Join` to avoid having to loop at all:

```
string commaSeparated = string.Join(", ", values);
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of the foreach-loop u can use the string.Join method. 
Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `String.Join(",", item);`
This means there is no ugly trimming or splitting that you have to do.

Answer (score 1):

I would use String.Join:

```
querybuilder = "SELECT Type, Text FROM [Element] WHERE Id IN( " + String.Join(",", CaseIdList.ToArray()) + ")";
```

I would also look into using Parameters instead of constructing SQL with strong concatenation - string concatenation is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, and parameters are easy to use.

How you would switch to parameters depends on how you're accessing the database, and which database engine, but a quick google search should help.

Answer (score 0):

```
querybuilder = ("SELECT Type, Text FROM [Element] WHERE Id IN( ");
foreach (var item in CaseIdList)
{
   querybuilder += item + ",";
}
querbuilder = querybuilder.TrimEnd(',');
querybuilder += ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`String.Trim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx):

> Removes all leading and trailing white-space characters from the current String object.

```
querybuilder = querybuilder.Trim(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Replace()`:

```
static void Main()
{
   string temp = "(a, b, c, d,)";
   temp = temp.Replace(",)", ")");

   Console.WriteLine(temp);
   Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ Aggregate and string.Format method:

```
    var items = CaseIdList.Select(p=>p.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).Aggregate((i,j)=>i+", "+j)
    querybuilder = string.Format("SELECT Type, Text FROM [Element] WHERE Id IN ({0})", items);
```

Answer (score 0):

Example using `StringBuilder`:

```
            var querybuilder  = new StringBuilder("SELECT Type, Text FROM [Element] WHERE Id IN(");
            foreach (var fragment in fragments)
            {
                querybuilder.Append(fragment);
                querybuilder.Append(',');
            }

            // note: we need to delete last line terminator
            querybuilder.Remove(querybuilder.Length - 1, 1);
            querybuilder.Append(')');
            return querybuilder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you are concatnating string too many times, you are losing performace because every time you do any operation on string var, it deallocates/allocates the entire string again in memory. You should use StringBuilder in such situations.

```
StringBuilder querybuilder = New StringBuilder();
querybuilder.Append("SELECT Type, Text FROM [Element] WHERE Id IN( "));
foreach (var item in CaseIdList) 
{    
    //querybuilder += item + ","; 
    querybuilder.Append(item);
    querybuilder.Append(",");
} 
//querybuilder += ")";
querybuilder.Remove(querybuilder.ToString().Length-1,1);
querybuilder.Append(")");
```